# Using Composer component with ReactWebChat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I'm using ReactWebChat to enable bot feature for the site I'm working on. I would need to implement programmatic sending of text to bot and useSendMessage hook is presented on the examples as a way to do it. As [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/docs/HOOKS.md) states, hooks only work from Composer children.

> To enable Web Chat API, all UI components must be located under the
> Composer component. You can refer to our plain UI customization
> sample for details.

When I try to combine Composer and ReactWebChat I get error

`botframework-webchat internal: <ActivityKeyerComposer> should not be nested.`

ActivityKeyerComposer runs twice and on the second run an existing context is found as it has just been successfully created on the first run. This errors blocks the bot from connecting.

My question is: Can Composer and ReactWebChat can be used simultaneously? None of the examples on the site show these components working together. If it is possible, any examples would be very welcome.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what it is you are actually trying to accomplish? And can you include the relevant code so we can see your implementation?

Comment: The project setup is so complicated that I really have nothing to present here. Basically, the setup is a multi-page website where minimizable chatbot would be accessible on all the pages. Several different react components along the pages would have button to send different keywords to bot. So basically, useSendMessage hook should be accessible throughtout the webapp while webchat is kind of a separate minimize/maximize modal type of component.